# Indesign javascript Socket always performs requests using host: localhost

Tags: javascript, sockets, adobe, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to use a Socket connection to read a file on a remote website. So far, my code:

```
conn = new Socket;
if( conn.open( 'example.com:80' ) ) {
    conn.write( 'GET /indesign-page/ HTTP/1.0' + "\n\n" );
    reply = conn.read(999999);
    conn.close();
} else {
    alert( 'Problem connecting to server' );
}
```

The socket connects to example.com fine, but the request comes across as this:

```
GET http://localhost/indesign-page/ HTTP/1.0
```

when it should be this:

```
GET http://example.com/indesign-page/ HTTP/1.0
```

I've tried changing the conn.write parameters to 'GET http://example.com/indesign-page/ ...', but then it comes across as:

```
GET http://localhosthttp://example.com/indesign-page/ HTTP/1.0
```

The webserver requires that the host be set correctly to serve correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the "Host" header.

```
conn.write( 'GET /indesign-page/ HTTP/1.0' + "Host: example.com\r\n" + "\n\n" );
```

Because `conn.open( 'example.com:80' )` means find example.com's server ip then connect that ip address at 80 port, so the web server does not know that you had resolved example.com before connected to it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use a manual socket object? On [Adobe's Community Site](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5668666?tstart=30) there's a mention to this already created [FTP Script](http://www.petertorpey.com/files/ae/scripts/FTPConnection.jsx) where you could call a GET or PUT to a file on a FTP server.

Otherwise which OS are you using?  If you'll always be on a Mac, you could shell out to an AppleScript command and place the file anywhere you'd like:

```
var command = 'do shell script "curl http://localhost/indesign-page"';
var response = app.doScript(command, ScriptLanguage.APPLESCRIPT_LANGUAGE);
```

The nice thing about the AppleScript is that you can execute the command manually using the AppleScript Editor (or Script Editor if you're earlier than 10.6).